# monodroid play video from assets

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-video-player

I am using monoandroid and I would like use that:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("Content/video.m4v");
            video.SetVideoURI (uri);
            video.Start();
```

In order to play the video but I am wrong on find the right path, how do that ?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this problem? I'm struggling with this too...

Comment: qu1ckdry, I got this working while publishing on a development tablet. After published the APK I always get "Can't play this video."

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to play sounds is to add the file in the Resources/Raw directory then use the following:

```
var player = global::Android.Media.MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.YourSound);
player.Start();
player.Completion += (m_sender, m_e) =>
{
player.Release();
player = null;
};
```